# Setup WAMP to be able to access from a mobile phone

Tags: wordpress, wamp

I am making a WordPress theme that should be served to mobile users. So far I have been testing it in Chrome using User agent spoofing. Now I would like to try and access it from a real mobile device.

On my PC I access the site using a virtual host that aims a folder on my computer. How do I do this from my phone, where I can't edit hosts file?

I found this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/395286/How-to-Access-WAMP-Server-in-LAN-or-WAN).

Regarding my httpd.conf file, I changed

```
Listen 80
```

to

```
Listen 192.168.xxx.xxx:8081
```

I also added to `<Directory "cgi-bin">`

```
Allow from all
```

The third thing I did was to open up port 8081.

Now, what I don't know is how to access my WordPress site from my phone, because when I type 192.168.xxx.xxx:8081 into the browser, I get Forbidden.

Comment: Check http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/98419/12615

Answer (score 0):

You can leave Listen 80 as is.  Just find out the IP of your machine and type that into your phone. http://192.168.xxx.xxx

Make sure your local machine's firewalls are configured properly to accept these connections.

If you have multiple virtual hosts, you can either make sure the site you are looking to test is listed first, or you may also be able to set DNS entries into your router / gateway if you are lucky.